# OSX App, cannot find the library when runnig

Tags: macos, libraries, links, app

I created an OSX app with graphical interface, MyNiceApp.app. This app uses wxWidgets library, so it needs the file libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.1.dylib .

When I run it on my Mac, everything is ok. However, when I run it on another Mac, it complains as follows:

```
 dyld[25231]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.1.dylib
   Referenced from: <XXX> /Users/pippo/Downloads/MyNiceApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyNiceApp
   Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.1.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/XXX/OS/usr/local/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.1.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
 Abort trap: 6
```

I want to put libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.1.dylib into MyNiceApp.app/Contents/Resources . How shall I tell the executable in MyNiceApp.app/Contents/MacOS/ that the library is in there ? Note that this path may change because the app may be moved !

Thank you